# playframework: WSRequestHolder holder = WS.url(url) -> error: no suitable method found for url(String)

Tags: java, web-services, playframework

I am having trouble trying to save some data in my application.  The relevant part of my code is:

```
 String url = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx/en";

   HashMap<Integer,String> id_name_env = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    WSRequestHolder holder =  WS.url(url); //here is the problem ...

          holder.setHeader("Cookie", "sessionid="+ session("sessionid"));

          holder.setContentType("application/json");

            ArrayList<Integer> envList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            WSResponse response = holder.get().get(20000);
            JsonNode content = response.asJson();
            List<String> listaIduri = content.findValuesAsText("id");

            for( String id : listaIduri){
                id_name_env.put(Integer.parseInt(id), id);
            }
```

and the error I get is:

> error: no suitable method found for url(String)

In Eclipse, it gives a different message:

> The method url(WSRequestHolderMagnet) in the type WS is not applicable for the arguments (String)

What am I doing wrong?  Is it a problem with the `url`? Eclipse is suggesting to change the `url` variable type into a `WSRequestHolderMagnet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are importing `play.api.libs.ws.WS` and that is to be used by Scala only. In general you can assume that something from `play.api.x.y.z` is to be used in Scala and it may have a `play.x.y.z` to be used in Java.

Try to import `play.libs.ws.WS` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem when i was migrating from play 2.2 toplay 2.3, i resolved it adding JavaWS dependency to the build.sbt and replacing the line "import play.api.libs.ws.*" by "import play.libs.ws.*".

You can read also Play 2.3 Migration guide.